# How do I resize an object in inkscape to an absolute size?

Tags: inkscape, resize

I have imported a dxf in inkscape, which is now converted into several paths resembling a logo. It has no round dimensions (i.e. many decimals) as it was processed multiple times to make it.

To use it in other software I want to resize it to well defined heights (e.g. 10 mm, 5 mm, 1 mm etc.) while retaining aspect ratio.

When using the transformation tool, I can only resize to relative sizes, not absolute. What could I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: Sample logo, resized]

I guess the source of your logo is not important (dxf). You like to resize it, so first mark the whole logo and group the elements (Ctrl-G) (fig.1).

Now you select X (2) and Y (3) position to 0, 0 and the group moves to point 4, the lower left point (maybe a matter of settings, but other points/directions work too).

Then you mark the lock symbol, for fixing the ratio (5) and insert the width (6) value, you like (in German B as Breite, H would be height/Höhe) and work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest way without any add on's or additional setup.

**"Clipping Mask Scaling - Trick"**

● Import image

● Go to sidebar to 'Create Rectangle and Square' and draw over (as accurately as possible) the object in photo which you know (for example)
 the width of.

● Select both Photo & Rectangle, go to Object > Clip > Set.

● Once clipped, select clipped image and enter the exact size (eg the width) in size dialogue in top toolbar, and press enter. (Ensure that when image is selected that aspect ratio is locked before scaling.) The object is now scale to actual size.

● To view fully scaled image, Select image, go to Object > Clip > Release. You now have the complete image, scaled to actual size.

Comment: While the solution you propose is described well and will probably work on images, it doesn't address my problem, because I don't have an image, but a drawing. I recommend you repost your answer along with a new question, written by yourself.

Comment: Object > clip > set doesn't seem to do anything. Changing its height make the text narrow and high instead of occupying several lines.